# Query to update all the null values to not null for all the columns in a single or dynamic query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am looking for a SQL query to update all the columns in table A which has a `NULL` value to `NOT NULL` values from table C using reference as table B. All the columns in table A should be updated using a single query or dynamic query. Values should be updated based on column name and values should not be hard coded.

Table A

```
  ID     Name   zip  city  Mdate
  10001  Sarah  NULL NULL  02-20-2018
  98765  AJ     NULL Ohio  01-15-2018
  12345  NULL   7511 Texas 03-08-2018
```

Table B

```
  ID      RollNo     Cdate
  12345   1          01-18-2018
  12345   2          01-22-2018
  12345   3          03-20-2018 
  98765   9          01-18-2018
  98765   8          01-22-2018
  98765   7          03-20-2018
  10001   10         03-08-2018 
  10001   11         01-15-2018
  10001   12         02-20-2018
```

TABLE C

```
  Rollno Name  Zip  City  Mdate         Cdate        Modifyby
  1      NULL  7511 Texas 01-18-2018   02-02-2017     @John 
  2      John  5001 NULL  01-22-2018   11-01-2017     @Krish
  3      NULL  7000 Ohio  03-20-2018   11-15-2017     @Maria 
  10     Sarah NULL NULL  03-08-2018   10-05-2017     @tom
  11     Tom   NULL NULL  01-15-2018   04-05-2017     @Sony
  12     NULL  5500 Pune  02-20-2018   03-25-2017     @Sandy  
  9      AJ    NULL Ohio  01-18-2018   10-07-2017     @Mandy
  8      NULL  NULL NULL  01-12-2018   11-02-2017     @Deck
  7      NUll  8000 NULL  01-12-2018   12-05-2017     @Ant
```

Output:

```
  ID     Name   zip  city  Mdate       Cdate          Modifyby   
  10001  Sarah  5500 Pune  02-20-2018  03-25-2017     @Sandy
  98765  AJ     8000 Ohio  01-18-2018  10-07-2017     @Mandy
  12345  John   7511 Texas 03-08-2018  10-05-2017     @tom
```

In the output, all the `NULL` column values in table A are updated with `NOT NULL` values from table C. Please provide a single query to update all the `NULL` columns in a single query itself.

I am trying below query but unable to update the table with max Function. Is there any alternative for it.

```
  Select * into #temp FROM

  (
  SELECT A.ID,
  Row_number() over(partition by A.ID order by A.mdate desc) as 
  RNK,C.NAME,C.ZIP,C.CITY,C.MDate,C.Cdate,C.Modifyby
  FROM tableA A
  INNER JOIN tableB B ON A.ID = B.ID
  INNER JOIN tableC C ON B.RollNo = C.RollNo
   )X where RNK = 1


  UPDATE  A SET Name = 
  CASE 
  WHEN MAX(A.Name) IS NULL THEN MAX(C.Name) 
   ELSE Max(A.Name) END
  , Zip = 
   CASE
    WHEN MAX(A.Zip) IS NULL THEN Max(C.Zip)
   ELSE MAX(A.Zip)
  END ,  
  City =CASE 
 WHEN MAX(A.City) IS NULL THEN Max(C.City) 
 ELSE MAX(A.City) 
 END
  FROM #temp A
 INNER JOIN TableB B ON A.ID = B.ID
 INNER JOIN tablec C ON B.RollNo = C.RollNo
```

Getting an error:

> An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement.

I need all the values in output table along with null values updated with not null values.

Comment: Why does `Rollno 11` in `TABLE C` have `Tom` as the name when it should be associated with `Sarah`?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: the value in table a 10001 has 3 child records in table c in that the latest record has sarah so it will be considered as final record irrespective of the other records. It applies to all the columns as well. Hope you got it.

Comment: Add any clarifications/additional info directly to the question [edit]

Comment: @dalek modified the requirement pls check

Answer (score 0):

Try this below script-

[DEMO HERE](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=cac3b2f0defebaf305ad3b4d7b4cfe70)

```
SELECT A.ID,
CASE 
    WHEN MAX(A.Name) IS NULL THEN MAX(C.Name) 
    ELSE Max(A.Name) 
END Name,
CASE
    WHEN MAX(A.Zip) IS NULL THEN Max(C.Zip)
    ELSE MAX(A.Zip)
END Zip,
CASE 
    WHEN MAX(A.City) IS NULL THEN Max(C.City) 
    ELSE MAX(A.City) 
END City,
A.MDate
FROM table_a A
INNER JOIN Table_B B ON A.ID = B.ID
INNER JOIN table_c C ON B.RollNo = C.RollNo
GROUP BY A.ID,A.MDate
```

Comment: This doesn't take account of OPs requirement to use the "latest" value where there are multiple values in TableC

Comment: Your changes are confusing. Do you required values from table C for the latest date per id?

Comment: @mkRabbani yes need the latest values based on the id and if the latest values have null values then should be updated with next not null values.